# Add Current Element's Class To Another Element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get my navigation links to change the css background of another element with jquery.

http://www.flcbranson.org/flcindex-new.php

Quite simply, mouseover li class="joinusonline" and header should become header class="joinusonline".
Mouseout and it goes back to header.

JJ

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Faith Life Church - Branson, MO</title>
    <script src="include/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // changes <header> background when mouseover <ul class="inheader"><li>
    $('.inheader li').hover(
        function(){$('header').addClass($(this).attr('class'))},
        function(){$('header').removeClass($(this).attr('class'))}
    )
    </script>
</head>
<body role="document">
<header role="banner">
    <h1><a href="http://www.flcbranson.org">Faith Life Church</a></h1>
</header>
<nav role="navigation">
    <h2>Main site navigation</h2>
    <ul class="inheader">
        <li class="joinusonline"><a href="flconlineservices.php">Join Us On-Line</a></li>
        <li class="areainformation"><a href="flcareainfo.php">Area Information</a></li>
        <li class="flcevents"><a href="flcevents.php"><abbr title="Faith Life Church">FLC</abbr> Events</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id="content" role="main">
    <h1 id="title">Welcome</h1>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
header {background:#003366 url() no-repeat center top;}
header.joinusonline {background-image:url(../images/backgrounds/header-joinusonline.jpg)}
header.areainformation {background-image:url(../images/backgrounds/header-areainformation.jpg)}
header.flcevents {background-image:url(../images/backgrounds/header-flcevents.jpg)}
```

Comment: This is JJ (I have a Stack login, now). While jfriend00's code worked, perfectly, I realize that I would rather have the link initiate the background change instead of the list item. This did not work (note that I replaced .inheader with .primarynavigation)... $(document).ready(function() { $('.primarynavigation li a').hover( function(){$('header').addClass($(this).parent().className)}, function(){$('header').removeClass($(this).parent().className)} ) }) I don't see any javascript errors in firebug, but it's not working. JJ

Answer (score 2):

I see you already have this code in your page:

```
$('.inheader li').hover(
    function(){$('header').addClass($(this).attr('class'))},
    function(){$('header').removeClass($(this).attr('class'))}
)
```

I think that code will do what you want, but you're executing it too early before the page is loaded.  You need to wrap it in `document.ready` like this (and I made one small optimization in how you fetch the className):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.inheader li').hover(
        function(){$('header').addClass(this.className)},
        function(){$('header').removeClass(this.className)}
    )
}
```

Or, you could also place what you have at the end of your page after the rest of the page has been parsed.

Comment: +1 It's obvious now you point it out. I've deleted my answer, which would have almost worked for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks...
That did exactly what I wanted.
JJ

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.joinusonline').mouseover(function() {
   $('header').addClass('joinusonline');
});

$('li.joinusonline').mouseout(function() {
   $('header').removeClass('joinusonline');
});
```